# Android/Java: EditText (Numeric) -> How do I create an onClick for the "Done"-Button?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I use eclipse and I need a solution for my Android-App.

In this App there is an EditText. Its inputType is set to number. If the user writes something  into this box and presses the button "Done" next to the numerical pad, the number is shown and the keyboard quits. But my aim is to use this "Done"-button for a simple additional task. By clicking this button I want the number written int the EditText saved in an integer variable. I know how to use buttons by checking or using the id but I don't know (how to get) the Id of this special "Done"-Button.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Please add some code to your question, e.g., anything related to the Done button.

Comment: I need 10 reputation to post a picture -.-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code

```
EditText editetext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editetext); // change this R.id.editetext to your EditText id
    Button doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doneButton); // change this R.id.doneButton to your Button id
            doneButton .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int num = Integer.parseInt(editetext.getText.toString);
            }
        });
```

**Update**

Try this to get done button action in keyboard

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            // do any thing here
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I need. My problem is:

I have an EditText. If I type something in this and than press "Done" next to the numbers it only quits the Keyboard. This I wanted to change. Your slution would work, but I really need this one! 

Do you know a solution for this?

Comment: Of cause your example would work if I would have the ID of the Button I search for. Do you know how I can find it out?

Comment: Is `Done` a button in your layout?

Comment: no, I mean the button next to the keyboard! If you press it the keyboard quits and you see your layout. I want to use this done button for more than just quit the keyboard.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it in a few minutes ;)

Comment: I don't quite get your code... Could you please explain it? It works but I don't know how ;)

Comment: See these links [setOnEditorActionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setOnEditorActionListener(android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener)) and [TextView.OnEditorActionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html)